# How can I count mouse clicks in Go?

Tags: go, mouseevent

I'm trying to write a program which counts the number of mouse left and right buttons presses every 30 seconds since start in order to get statistics of mouse activity. But it doesn't count single rightclick, it counts rightclick as leftclick + rightclick combination. Also it doesn't output results after 30 seconds even if there was no clicks at all, instead it waits mouse button pressing after 30 seconds passed. I'm stumped. What should I change to fix this? Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
    "time"
)

const t = 30

func leftclickcounter () (int) {
    nowTime := time.Now().Unix()
    nowTime = time.Now().Unix()
    NumOfLeftClick := 0
    for {
        lmb := robotgo.AddMouse("left" )
        if lmb {
            fmt.Println("leftclick")
            NumOfLeftClick++
        }
        if time.Now().Unix()-nowTime >= t {
            return NumOfLeftClick
        }
    }
}

func rightclickcounter () (int) {
    nowTime := time.Now().Unix()
    nowTime = time.Now().Unix()
    NumOfRightClick := 0
    for {
        rmb := robotgo.AddMouse("right")
        if rmb {
            fmt.Println("rightclick")
            NumOfRightClick++
        }
        if time.Now().Unix() - nowTime >= t {
            return NumOfRightClick
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    for {
        lc := leftclickcounter()
        rc := rightclickcounter()
        fmt.Println("Number of leftclicks:", lc)
        fmt.Println("Number of rightclicks:", rc)
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign a value to `nowTime` twice in a row?

Comment: To catch 30 seconds difference between them

Comment: There is no difference between them (maybe a few µs): `nowTime := time.Now().Unix()` then on _the very next line_: `nowTime = time.Now().Unix()`.  You're completely ignoring the firt value anyway (even if it happens to be a few clock ticks different)

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for your observation and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the elapsed time  mentioned by [Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860/flimzy)

You are running an infinite loop within an infinite loop, rightclickcounter() gets never executed. At least not in your timeframe.

Currently, you are starting lc counter -> wait 30 secs -> start rc counter -> wait 30 secs

```golang
for {
        lc := leftclickcounter()
        rc := rightclickcounter()
        fmt.Println("Number of leftclicks:", lc)
        fmt.Println("Number of rightclicks:", rc)
    }
```

take a look at https://gobyexample.com/goroutines and https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2